# How to run Java Swing in Netbeans?

Tags: java

I've been trying to run gui in netbeans using java swing but it won't run at all. All the projects that I execcute that uses jframe does not run. Any tips on how to fix this thing? This is how it looks like: [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the Projects pane of your IDE (on the left), right-click on the Project title (**OfficeManagementSystem**). Select **Proprties** located at the bottom of the popup menu that appears. You are presented with a Properties Dialog window. In the **Categories** pane on the left of the Properties dialog window, select the **Run** item. In the right pane, select the button with the **Browse...** caption to the right side of the **Main Class:** text field. Select your startup form then hit the **Select Main Class** button. Now select the **OK** button to close the Properties Dialog Window. RUN!

Comment: it says no main class found? huhu why i'll edit this post to add the screenshots

Comment: its now updated, hope yyou can help :(

Comment: Within the first Image, I can see the JavaDoc that states: `@param args the command line arguments`. Is that not attached to a **main()** method? I can't tell because the image doesn't show that far down. It should be.

Comment: https://github.com/MuhammadTahaAzam1997/HospitalManagementSystemusingJAVASwing this is the source code that I wished to run but then the above error shows

Comment: some of my friends was able to run it without any errors but when i try to run this, such error occurs? :( idk what to do

Comment: [See my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65196393/4725875)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to run with no problems using NetBeans IDE 8.2. Let's start from the beginning.

Delete your current **OfficeManagementSystem** project from your IDE and local drive system. Select the **OfficeManagementSystem** project located within your IDE Project pane located on the left side of the IDE. Right-click on it and select the **Delete** popup menu item. A Delete Project dialog is displayed. Check-mark the `Also delete sources under .....` checkbox then select the <kbd>Yes</kbd> button.

**Close NetBeans!**

To make sure all is gone, open your file browser (in Windows10 this is named **File Explorer** [*win key + E*]) and navigate to your NetBeans Projects folder. Default location in Windows is `C:\Users\{yourAccountName}\Documents\NetBeansProjects\`. Make sure that **OfficeManagementSystem** project folder is deleted.

With your web browser, go to the [Source Code Web Page](https://github.com/MuhammadTahaAzam1997/HospitalManagementSystemusingJAVASwing) and select the **Code** button:

[image]

Then from the dropdown menu select **Download ZIP**:

[image]

A **Save File** dialog will appear possibly similar to this:

[image]

Select the **Save File** option then select the <kbd>OK</kbd> button. Choose a location to save the ZIP file and remember it.

Navigate to you downloaded file named **HospitalManagementSystemusingJAVASwing-master.zip** and Un-Zip it with your favorite decompression software like **WinRar** or **7Zip**. Have it unzip into its **own folder**.

Navigate to and open the the folder created by your decompression software, it should have been named **HospitalManagementSystemusingJAVASwing-master**. If done properly you should have yet another folder (a sub-folder) also named **HospitalManagementSystemusingJAVASwing-master**. Rename this folder to **HospitalManagementSystem** by right-clicking on the folder and selecting **Rename** from the popup menu. Delete the unnecessary text within the name then hit your <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key.

After Renaming the folder, once again right-click on it and select **Copy** from the popup menu.

As described earlier, navigate to you **NetBeansProjects** directory (folder) and double-click on it. Paste the new **HospitalManagementSystem** folder into the **NetBeansProjects** folder. This project will now be added to the NetBeans Projects List.

**Start NetBeans!**

Once NetBeans has completely started, from the menu bar select the **File ➞ Open Project...** menu item. The **Open Project** dialog will be displayed. Scroll down the left pane of this dialog until you see **HospitalManagementSystem** and select it. Now hit the <kbd>Open Project</kbd> button. This project will load into the NetBeans IDE Projects pane located on the left side of your IDE under the name of: **OfficeManagementSystem**. Why this person changed the project name at this point is beyond me but to each their own.

Expand the project and its active package (officemanagementsystem) so as to expose all the classes involved. You should see the following listed:

```
LoginPage.java               // The first Form we want displayed.
MenuPage.java                // The Menu page (once login is achieved).
Module1.java                 // Should really be named PatientPage
Module2.java                 // Should really be named DoctorAvailabilityPage.
OfficeManagementSystem.java  // The application start-up class.
```

**This application still will not run** since it contains nothing within the **main()** method of the start-up class (**OfficeManagementSystem**). Open this class into the IDE Editor by double-clicking on it.

Expand the **main()** method code block and add this code line into it:

```
new LoginPage().setVisible(true);
```

**Run the application!** The first Window displayed will be the Login Page. Username is: **admin** and the password is: **admin**. (change in code if you like). And away you go. :)

Answer (score 0):

All java applications need a static main method as a bootstrap.
It should look something like the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { YourJFrameClass frame = new YourJFrameClass(); }
```

That should get you started.

Comment: why do this occur? i have a friend who tried to run this EXACT SAME program but does not encounter any error

Comment: @Roshiya is probably on to something. Does your OfficeManagementSystem.java have a main method? If so you are just attempting to start the wrong class.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is to press Shift+F11 (Clean and Build Project), then hit F6 to run it.

It refreshes Netbeans appropriately and finds your main without all the manual labor; and if you have multiple mains, it will give you the option to select the correct one.

Comment: it says no main class but in the source code there is

Answer (score 0):

Check if your JFrame Class has this method:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
   java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new YOURFORMNAME().setVisible(true);
            }
   });
}
```

The `setVisibile(true)` allows the form to be visible to the user. The `main` method is used to define the entry point for the application therefore this method is needed to run the `JFrame`